# Difference Between Scala Expressions

Tags: scala, scalameta

Up until recently it was my understanding that two Scala statements below were interchangeable.

```
expr.op(arg1, arg2,...)
expr op (arg1, arg2,...)
```

But I've playing around with scala meta, looked at the resulting AST they generate,

```
Term.Apply(Term.Select(<exprTerm>, Term.Name("op")), Seq(<argTerm1>, <argTerm2>,...))
Term.ApplyInfix(<exprTerm>, Term.Name("op"), Nil, Seq(<argTerm1>, <argTerm2>,...))
```

and found a `Nil` in the AST for the infix expression.  Digging further, I found out that the infix option allows for type parameters:

```
expr op [Type1, Type2,...] (arg1, arg2,...)
```

In this context, I don't understand what purpose they'd serve.  When would they be usefull?  Why are they allowed on infix operations but not "apply-select" operations (`expr.op(arg1, arg2,...)`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types are not params types, but generics. For example:

```
object expr {
  def op1(param1: Any, param2: Any) = ()
  def op2[T](param1: Any, param2: Any) = ()
}
```

And we will get

```
expr op1 (1, 2)
// Term.ApplyInfix(Term.Name("expr"), Term.Name("op1"), Nil, List(Lit.Int(1), Lit.Int(2)))
expr op2[Int] (1, 2)
// Term.ApplyInfix(Term.Name("expr"), Term.Name("op2"), List(Type.Name("Int")), List(Lit.Int(1), Lit.Int(2)))
```

And postfix variant:

```
expr.op1[Int](1, 2)
//Term.Apply(Term.ApplyType(Term.Select(Term.Name("expr"), Term.Name("op1")), List(Type.Name("Int"))), List(Lit.Int(1), Lit.Int(2)))
```

But in `scalac` if you run it with `-Xprint:typer` for code

```
object Test5 {
  object expr {
    def op1(param1: Any, param2: Any): Unit = {}
    def op2[T](param1: Any, param2: Any): Unit = {}
  }

  expr.op1("", "", "")
  expr op1 ("", "", "")

  expr.op2[Int]("", "", "")
  expr op2[Int] ("", "", "")
}
```

you will see that pairs of postfix and infix notations are parsed the same in syntax tree:

```
Test5.this.expr.op1("", "", "");
Test5.this.expr.op1("", "", "");
Test5.this.expr.op2[Int]("", "", "");
Test5.this.expr.op2[Int]("", "", "")
```